# LazyLoading with ManyToMany worked as EAGER

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many, lazy-loading

I have relation many to many between Film and Actor tables

```
@Table(...)
public class Film extends SuperId {
...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "films_actors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="film_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="actor_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

And Actor's entity

```
@Table
public class Actor extends SuperId {
...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Film> films = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

But when i trying to retrieve All films with SpringData methods or Methods based on the Criteria builder, I get All films with initialized all related Actors and other lazy related entities

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<Film> findAllLazy(Pageable pageable) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Film> query = cb.createQuery(Film.class);
    Root<Film> root = query.from(Film.class);
    query.select(root)
            .distinct(true)
            .orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(Film_.rating)));
    return em.createQuery(query)
            .setFirstResult((pageable.getPageNumber()) * pageable.getPageSize())
            .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
            .getResultList();
}
```

Comment: How does the SQL look like that Hibernate executes?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli `select distinct ... from films order ...` but when I try to look what contains in the set, I get retrieving all related entities

Comment: _'I try to look what contains in the set'_ how and where exactly are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the actors set in the Debugger will trigger the loading of the lazy loaded collection.

So the lazy loading works as expected.